# Is a minimal finger length required to make hook grip effective?

Tags: weightlifting, grip

I am playing with hook grip sometimes, and for me it is weaker grip than regular grip.

- with hook grip I lift a smaller maximal weight,
- with hook grip I can hold submaximal weight for smaller duration,
- the same apply for double or single arm holds/lifts

I cannot properly grab my thumb with the other fingers, I guess I cannot reach it properly.

Is there some minimal finger length required to make the hook grip worthy? Or is it just about proper technique and skill?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is why the bars used in women's Olympic weightlifting competition have a smaller diameter, of 25mm, rather than the 28mm used for the men's bars. This is intended to allow hook grip despite women typically having shorter fingers than men. (For comparison, bars used in powerlifting typically have a 27mm diameter for a dedicated deadlift bar, or 28-29mm for a power bar. Dedicated squat bars may be 32-35mm thick.)

If your fingers are not long enough (or your bar is too thick) to allow you to cover your thumbnail with your fingertips while holding the bar, then your hook grip will be compromised.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. If you can post a picture detail how looks sufficient and un-sufficient thumb/finger cover, it would be the ultimately best.